# Issues setting up remote node debugging with WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm, remote-debugging, pm2

I've started my application on my server with pm2:

```
pm2 start /path/lib/start-server.js --name="cdl-debug" -- --inspect
```

Which would be equivalent to `node /path/lib/start-server.js --inspect`

The application starts and runs, although I see no notice in the logs about any debugging like explained [here](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_v8_inspector_integration_for_node_js)

I've opened up port 9229 in the firewall and setup my WebStorm debug config with `Attach to Node.js/Chrome` like so:

[image]

Then when I run the debugger it tries to connect for a while and finally fails with the message: `Connection timed out. No further information.`

Is there something else I should do? The [WebStorm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#remote_debugging) doesn't mention much about the required setup on the server.

Answer (score 3):

When running `node /path/lib/start-server.js --inspect`, you are passing `--inspect` to your application, not to Node.js. As a result, debugger is not started. You need to make sure to pass `--inspect-brk` to Node.js in order to debug your app:

`node --inspect-brk /path/lib/start-server.js`

You can specify `--inspect-brk` in your [pm2 process.json](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/), like

```
"node_args": [
      "--inspect-brk=7000"
    ]
```

and then start your app with `pm2 start process.json`

Comment: thank you that probably resolved part of the problem. I now see in the logs that the debugger started. WebStorm however still gives the same connection error when I try to start the debugger

Comment: what port did you start the debugger on? it should match the port specified in run configuration. I.e., when using `--inspect-brk=7000`, you have to specify port `7000` in run configuration